# How to manage music ipod touch 4g ios6 ubuntu 13.04

Tags: sync, music, ipod, ios

I am using **ubuntu 13.04** and my ipod has has **ios6**, and its **4g**. I have already tried **libimobiledevice** and also tried it with gtkp which says "Error initialising iPod: Unsupported checksum type". I really want this feature as I do **not** want to depend on windows for my music transfer to ipod. I don mind if I have to manually organize my music (instead of syncing i mean) but i really want to make it work help please!

Comment: What's the question, exactly? Sounds like a bug.

Comment: I had searched many websites until I arrived at this working wondeful answer with the tapmedia app.
I did not manage to initiade the touch pod in rhythmbox or gtkpod, but now that's obsolete. Works very fine with ubuntu 12.10 as well. THANK YOU!!
--ppo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if `gtkp` is the same as `gtkpod`, but I used to use that for managing my iPhone and it worked best of all the things I tried. It's been a while, but I think you need `ifuse` with it.

I would give you more information from their page but it seems to be down at the moment. Otherwise you can try yourself: [gtkpod](http://www.gtkpod.org/). I had an iPhone 3GS at the time and it handled that fine.

Comment: It did not work your way but I managed to doit by installing mewseek and using its import function. Thanks for replaying anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to kracheck, member of kubuntu Forums (www.kubuntuforums.net) now I can transfer music from my Ubuntu 12.04 laptop to an iPod Touch 4g, running iOS 6.3.1 using File Manager app on the ipod (from TapMedia Ltd.) which is a free app and has an integrated player (right, I'm not using the native "music" app on the iPod, the music database is empty there).

Here are the steps:

On the iPod - Install the File Manager (from TapMedia, Ltd.) app

On Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install ifuse
sudo apt-get install ideviceinstaller
```

Thats it, I connected the iPod to a USB slot on the laptop and Nautilus launched, showing the FileManager app icon. I selected the icon and that took me to a "Documents" folder, went to that folder and then from another Nautilus windos I only had to drag and drop my selected songs (I had to go up one folder and went back to Documents to see fhe file, if you stay there after transfer completes, the file is missing, if you go up and back the files are there)

Unmount the device, go to the FileManager app on the iPod, go to Documents folder and your songs are there. Select a song and tne included player starts playing the song.